# Redirecting to a subdomain using a variable(Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to redirect from a directory to a subdomain in Ruby on Rails.

As it is, it goes to `slug.example.com`. How can I redirect it to `xxx.example.com`?

```rb
# slug = 'xxx'

get '/users/:slug', to: redirect(subdomain: 'slug', path: '')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a block as documented in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection and https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html#method-i-redirect.

But proably hte easiest way is to subclass the existing OptionRedirect class:

```rb
class SubdomainFromSlugRedirect < ActionDispatch::Routing::OptionRedirect
  # something that won't appear in your routes
  SUBDOMAIN_TOKEN = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm' 

  def options
    super.merge(subdomain: SUBDOMAIN_TOKEN)
  end

  def path(params, _request)
    super.sub(SUBDOMAIN_TOKEN, params[:slug])
  end
end
```

and then use it in the router

```rb
get '/users/:slug', to: redirect(SubdomainFromSlugRedirect)
```